# Package Dependencies Error in almost every install

Tags: 11.04, dependencies

New to Ubuntu.  In **other software sources** I have "Debian 4.0 eth" officially supported "non-us.debian.org/"; etc ... "ppa.launcpad.net" and installing applications has stopped working.

I think i first came across this problem after installing Blender 2.58

When using update manager it is prompting for a partial upgrade.

When trying to install almost any software I get the same error `Package Dependencies Error` or `GPG PUB KEY` missing.

Output of: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

```
Ign http:///non-us.debian.org stable/non-US InRelease
Ign http:///non-us.debian.org stable/non-US Release.gpg
Ign http:///non-us.debian.org stable/non-US Release
Ign http://non-us.debian.org stable/non-US/contrib TranslationIndex
Ign http://non-us.debian.org stable/non-US/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://non-us.debian.org stable/non-US/non-free TranslationIndex
Err http://non-us.debian.org stable/non-US/main Sources
  503  Service Unavailable
Err http://non-us.debian.org stable/non-US/contrib Sources
  503  Service Unavailable
Err http://non-us.debian.org stable/non-US/non-free Sources
  503  Service Unavailable
Err http://non-us.debian.org stable/non-US/main amd64 Packages
  503  Service Unavailable
Err http://non-us.debian.org stable/non-US/contrib amd64 Packages
  503  Service Unavailable
Err http://non-us.debian.org stable/non-US/non-free amd64 Packages
  503  Service Unavailable
Ign http://non-us.debian.org stable/non-US/contrib Translation-en_IN
Ign http://non-us.debian.org stable/non-US/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://non-us.debian.org stable/non-US/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://non-us.debian.org stable/non-US/main Translation-en
Ign http://non-us.debian.org stable/non-US/non-free Translation-en_IN
Ign http://non-us.debian.org stable/non-US/non-free Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com natty InRelease
Ign http://archive.canonical.com natty InRelease
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com natty InRelease
Ign http://http.us.debian.org stable InRelease
Ign http://ftp.us.debian.org etch InRelease
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates InRelease
Hit http://archive.canonical.com natty Release.gpg
Get:1 http://extras.ubuntu.com natty Release.gpg [72 B]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease
Get:2 http://http.us.debian.org stable Release.gpg [1,672 B]
Ign http://linux.dropbox.com natty InRelease
Ign http://ftp.us.debian.org etch Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com natty-security InRelease
Hit http://archive.canonical.com natty Release
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com natty Release
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease        
Hit http://archive.canonical.com natty/partner amd64 Packages
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com natty/main amd64 Packages
Get:7 http://linux.dropbox.com natty/main amd64 Packages [784 B]  
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com natty-security Release.gpg [198 B]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease                       
Ign http://archive.canonical.com natty/partner TranslationIndex
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com natty/main TranslationIndex
Get:9 http://http.us.debian.org stable Release [104 kB]  
Ign http://linux.dropbox.com natty/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com natty Release               
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease
Ign http://http.us.debian.org stable Release                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates Release
Get:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease [316 B]         
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com natty-security Release             
Get:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease [316 B]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com natty/restricted Sources          
Get:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release.gpg [316 B]       
Ign http://http.us.debian.org stable/main Sources/DiffIndex  
Get:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release.gpg [316 B]           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com natty/main Sources                 
Ign http://ftp.us.debian.org etch/contrib TranslationIndex
Ign http://http.us.debian.org stable/contrib Sources/DiffIndex
Get:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release.gpg [1,502 B]
Ign http://http.us.debian.org stable/non-free Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://ftp.us.debian.org etch/main TranslationIndex
Get:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release.gpg [1,928 B]
Ign http://http.us.debian.org stable/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ftp.us.debian.org etch/non-free TranslationIndex
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release.gpg
Hit http://http.us.debian.org stable/contrib amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
W: GPG error: http://http.us.debian.org stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY AED4B06F473041FA NO_PUBKEY 64481591B98321F9
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease: File /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ppa.launchpad.net_sunab_kdenlive-release_ubuntu_dists_natty_InRelease doesn't start with a clearsigned message
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease: File /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ppa.launchpad.net_ubuntu-wine_ppa_ubuntu_dists_natty_InRelease doesn't start with a clearsigned message
E: Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/http.us.debian.org_debian_dists_stable_contrib_binary-amd64_Packages.IndexDiff - open (2: No such file or directory)
```

`cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 11.04 _Natty Narwhal_ - Release amd64 (20110427.1)]/ natty main restricted

# See http:/help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http:/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty main restricted
deb-src http:/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty restricted main multiverse universe #Added by software-properties

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http:/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-updates main restricted
deb-src http:/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-updates restricted main multiverse universe #Added by software-properties

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http:/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty universe
deb http:/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http:/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty multiverse
deb http:/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-updates multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'backports'
## repository.
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http:/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http:/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http:/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-security main restricted
deb-src http:/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-security restricted main multiverse universe #Added by software-properties
deb http:/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-security universe
deb http:/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http:/archive.canonical.com/ubuntu natty partner
deb-src http:/archive.canonical.com/ubuntu natty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http:/extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty main
deb-src http:/extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty main
deb http:/ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ etch main contrib non-free
deb-src http:/ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ etch main contrib non-free
deb http:/http.us.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
deb-src http:/http.us.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
deb http:/non-us.debian.org/debian-non-US stable/non-US main contrib non-free
deb-src http:/non-us.debian.org/debian-non-US stable/non-US main contrib non-free
```

After removing Debian repositories I'm still getting this error:

```
    W:GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 9BDB3D89CE49EC21,
 W:GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 80E7349A06ED541C,
 W:GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8C851674F96FD737,
 W:GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 94E58C34A8670E8C, 
E:Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_natty-updates_multiverse_i18n_Index (1)
```

I actually tried this before, but i am always getting this error

```
--Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /etc/apt/secring.gpg --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 8C851674F96FD737
gpg: requesting key F96FD737 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
?: keyserver.ubuntu.com: Connection refused
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Connection refused
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

Comment: please run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` in a terminal.  Copy and paste the output into your question.

Comment: Question Updated with the output to - sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: Debian Etch is outdated (from 2007) and not supported as of 2010. The current supported Debian versions are Lenny and Squeeze. Those repositories do not belong to Ubuntu as they might be incompatible.

Comment: @BETA - for your last edit - are you behind some-sort of firewall - or possibly are you using some-sort of proxy?

Comment: @fossfreedom yeah i connect through the proxy servers of the institute.

Comment: thought so - see my amended answer for how to fix GPG errors behind a proxy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Diagnosis

From your latest edit, the errors are most probably due to the debian sources in your repository lists.

This could cause all sorts of conflicts with the standard ubuntu repositories - my initial reaction would be to disable these non-ubuntu repositories rather than downloading the public key from the debian site.

Re-run after removal of the debian repos.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It perhaps also worth adding the output of the following so that we can confirm what other repo issues you may have:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

### How to fix

I'm not sure why you have added the Debian Etch repositories - perhaps you can add that answer to your question.

To comment out these repositories:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

find the lines:

```
deb http:/ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ etch main contrib non-free
deb-src http:/ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ etch main contrib non-free
deb http:/http.us.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
deb-src http:/http.us.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
deb http:/non-us.debian.org/debian-non-US stable/non-US main contrib non-free
deb-src http:/non-us.debian.org/debian-non-US stable/non-US main contrib non-free
```

add a "#" if front of them i.e. so that it looks like:

```
#deb http:/ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ etch main contrib non-free
#deb-src http:/ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ etch main contrib non-free
#deb http:/http.us.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
#deb-src http:/http.us.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
#deb http:/non-us.debian.org/debian-non-US stable/non-US main contrib non-free
#deb-src http:/non-us.debian.org/debian-non-US stable/non-US main contrib non-free
```

Write out the file (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>) and exit the editor (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>).

re-run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Confirm that everything is OK.

### How to fix missing GPG keys

For each hexadecimal string prefix `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys`

for example:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 9BDB3D89CE49EC21
```

Repeat for each missing GPG key

### How to fix missing GPG keys behind a proxy

The above instructions will not work if you are behind a proxy.  Fortunately the webupd8 team ([click for installation instructions](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/launchpad-getkeys-gets-proxy-support.html)) have a solution.  You don't necessarily need to install the PPA - you could also download the natty deb from [here](https://launchpad.net/%7Enilarimogard/+archive/webupd8/+packages?field.name_filter=keys&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=natty) and install manually.

How to use `launchpad-getkeys` behind a proxy are in the webupd8 link above.

### How to install blender 2.58 in ubuntu

Try to stick to the official ubuntu repositories - it will give you the most stable system.

In you ubuntu you can install newer versions of software from others that have packaged the software on Launchpad - see the related questions below.

One such repository is this developer for blender - note - the only reason I've linked to this is that Google has revealed a few blog sites that have linked to this particular repository.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:cheleb/blender-svn/ubuntu
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install blender
```

---

Related Questions:

- [image: Stack Overflow] [Are "PPA's" safe to add to my system, and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)
- [image: Stack Overflow] [How to install ppa packages in an apt-get style](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16211/how-to-install-ppa-packages-in-an-apt-get-style)

Comment: New to Ubuntu, can you please provide some details for removing non ubuntu debian repositories. In the other sofware sources i have "Debian 4.0 eth" officially supported "non-us.debian.org/"; etc ... "ppa.launcpad.net"; ... which ones to remove?? and will applications depending on them stop working, i think i first came across this problem after installing Blender 2.58, will that stop working

Comment: Tried commenting out the debian sources, but what i found out is that the "source.list" file is empty, it doesn't have any text.
Any Suggestion.

Comment: sorry - my bad - forgot the "s" in sources.list.  Have corrected the answer now.

Comment: Removed debian sources still getting error-(look end of quetion)

Comment: ... oh dear - this is exactly what happens when your package management system is screwed up.  Look at my amended answer on how to fix GPG keys.  Please also amend the formatting of the last change in your question - the last edit is impossible to read.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem with an ubuntu. I just needed to restart `squid-deb-proxy` and after it everything returend to  normal.