# How to install a HP LaserJet P1102w?

Tags: printing, hardware, hp

I just did an install of the hp laserjet P1102w printer and it's not working. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, and I went to see if I had hplip installed and it said I did.

How do I set up this printer?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/58101/

Comment: this worked for me setting up a Laserjet P1102w over lan on Lubuntu 15.10: http://askubuntu.com/a/575568/124393

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 and tried to use my HP LaseJet P1102w but it wouldn't respond to the printing requests, neither with Wi-Fi or USB cable connected. Ubuntu 13.10 already comes with this printer pre-configured with default settings. You should be able to just choose it on a list and use, with no need to "add a new printer".

However, for me the default setting (HPLIP libary and driver 'hpcups 3.13.9') didn't work. When you send a request to the printer, the LED blinks but nothing else happends. Switching to the alternative driver 'Foomatic/foo2zjs-z2', already included with Ubuntu 13.10, solved the problem. Now it works via Wi-Fi or USB cable.

In case you don't know how to, or don't want to, change the default instalation, you can add a new printer following this step-by-step:

1) Turn on you printer

2) Go to 'System Settings' and 'Printers'

3) Choose 'Add printer'

4) Select your printer on the list of Wi-Fi printers brodcasting on your area (Network printers). If you prefer to connect to the printer via USB, just connect the cable, prior to this step, and choose the printer shown to be connected via cable, shown on the top of the instalation window.

5) Choose the 'HPLIP' option that will show up on the right frame.

6) Enter the names you want to use to identify it and click OK, to finish. Your printer should have been added now to the list of installed printers.

7) Double-click on you printer icon, to go to the properties.

8) Click on 'Change' at 'Make and Model'.

9) Choose 'HP' on the list of manufacturers.

10) Choose model 'LaserJet Pro P1102w' and the only driver that will show up  (Foomatic/foo2zjs-z2). If you choose the recommended model 'LaserJet Professional P1102w' the driver option that will show up is 'hpcups 3.13.9', which, at least for me, didn't work out. Click next.

11) I recommend to choose 'new PPD', although the re-use of an older PPD can also be used. Click Apply.

12) Your printer should be responding properly now.

If it works for you or not, leave a feedback and/or rate this question/answer to help the Ubuntu Community to improve the system!

Cheers!

Comment: ANSWER UPDATE: the problem persists with Ubuntu 14.04, although the driver 'hpcups' has been updated to version 3.14.3. The solution, pointed previously, remains working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I did the following under 14.04: check at hplipopensource.com the Basic HPLIP Troubleshooting steps.
In my case the missing PPD could be easly installed via entering "hp-setup" in a terminal window. Just follow the instruction, ensure that printer is connected to the WiFi, PPD will be downloaded from HP and printer is installed and working fine.