# HP laserjet p1102w can't disable smart install

Tags: drivers, printing, hp, laserjet

I'm trying to install my HP laserjet professional p1102w printer via usb on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I'm focusing on getting it to work locally because I think wirelessly is probably more unstable or takes more time to try fix.

It has worked with windows before, but I switched to Linux recently.

I found my printer on System settings/printers. I actually found two, probably because it was also used wirelessly at some point. I don't remember at what stage, but I decided to delete them both. Now they are not there.

I tried hplip using [this page on hplipopensource](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/laserjet/hp_laserjet_professional_p1102w.html)

using **hp-setup**, when I do discover device via usb, I get a popup that wants to disable smart install. I accept but I get this error message:

> Failed to disable smart install. 
>   Please refer to http://hplipopensource.com/node/367

I go to the link and try method nr 2. (Because my printer doesn't have a front panel which is required for method 1).

When I run **hp-doctor** I get error:

> HPLIP cannot detect devices in your network. This may be due to
>   existing firewall settings blocking the required ports like
>   (5353/udp). When you are in a trusted network environment, you may
>   open the ports for network services like mdns and slp in the firewall.
>   For detailed steps see http://hplipopensource.com/node/375

I follow the link and I don't understand where I should go. I just skip that step for now and try **hp-doctor**:

I updated repository and installed all missing/incompatible packages.

After that, it says:

```
error: Smart Install is enabled in "HP LaserJet Professional P 1102w" device(s).  
Do you want to download and disable smart install?(y=yes*, n=no):
```

After I agree, I get a crash report that doctor.py has stopped unexpectedly and this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/hp-doctor", line 328, in <module> queues.main_function(core.passwordObj, MODE,ui_toolkit, False, DEVICE_URI)   
File "/usr/share/hplip/base/queues.py", line 349, in  main_function SI_sts, error_str = smart_install.disable(mode, '', None, None, passwordObj)
File "/usr/share/hplip/base/smart_install.py", line 253, in disable sts, smart_install_run, smart_install_asc, error_str = download(mode, passwordObj)   
File "/usr/share/hplip/base/smart_install.py", line 192, in download digsig_sts, smart_install_run, smart_install_asc, error_str = validate(mode, smart_install_run, smart_install_asc)   
File "/usr/share/hplip/base/smart_install.py", line 154, in validate calc_checksum = utils.get_checksum(open(smart_install_run, 'r').read())
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final) 
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 9529: invalid start byte
```

I’m skipping that to try method nr 3 but I don’t get any information about bInterfaceClass:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 03f0:102a Hewlett-Packard  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 049f:000e Compaq Computer Corp. Internet Keyboard 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 1bcf:0007 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Optical Mouse 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub f

$ lsusb -s 001:002
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 03f0:102a Hewlett-Packard 
$ lsusb -s 001:002 | grep bInterfaceClass
$
```

Even though I didn’t get any info I tried:

```
$ sudo -i
# su -c "gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 0xA59047B9"
gpg: keyring `/root/.gnupg/secring.gpg' created gpg: keyring `/root/.gnupg/pubring.gpg' created 
gpg: requesting key A59047B9 from hkp server pgp.mit.edu
gpgkeys: key A59047B9 can't be retrieved
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found. 
gpg: Total number processed: 0 
gpg: keyserver communications error: keyserver helper general error 
gpg: keyserver communications error: unknown pubkey algorithm  
gpg: keyserver receive failed: unknown pubkey algorithm
```

I don’t understand what validation of the digital signature is. The next step didn’t work either:

```
# su -c "gpg --verify SmartInstallDisable-Tool.run.asc SmartInstallDisable-Tool.run"
gpg: can't open `SmartInstallDisable-Tool.run.asc' 
gpg: verify signatures failed: file open error
```

And the last step didn’t work either:

```
# sh SmartInstallDisable-Tool.run
sh: 0: Can't open SmartInstallDisable-Tool.run
```

I also tried following this:
[How to install a HP LaserJet P1102w?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343014/how-to-install-a-hp-laserjet-p1102w)

But at settings and adding a printer, the printer doesn't show up in the list (not locally or as a network connection).

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps with the printer connected

1. Deactivate the smart install function using these instructions [Deactivate smart install](http://hplipopensource.com/node/367)

   - [Download SmartInstallDisable-Tool.run](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/smartinstall/SmartInstallDisable-Tool.run).
   - Follow the instructions to execute the SmartInstallDisable-Tool, you can skip step "C" just do step "D"

     > d. Run command  "sh
     >   SmartInstallDisable-Tool.run" in terminal to disable smart install feature in the device.

     You will see an error in your console like this:

     ```
      sh: SmartInstallDisable-Tool.run
      Creating directory SmartInstallDisable-Tool
      Verifying archive integrity... All good.
      Uncompressing Smart Install Disable Utility Self
      Extracting Archive...........
      [SMART INSTALL DISABLE UTILITY]
      Libusb package is not installed. Please install the libusb-1.0/libusb-0.1 package from the package manager and re-run this script
     ```

     To fix it you just have to install this package

     ```
      sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev
     ```

     like this page explains [How to install libusb correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853389/how-to-install-libusb-in-ubuntu)
   - Now you can run in your terminal `sh SmartInstallDisable-Tool.run` without any error.
2. You will see that the printer will start installing, but the default installation that the system makes does not work, so proceed as below
3. Install `hplip-gui` if not already installed.
4. Now run this command to start hplip-gui

   ```
   sudo hp-setup
   ```
5. Select USB in the graphic user interface; your printer will appear; select it and click next then follow any prompts in the terminal to complete installation

NOTE: in your printer settings you would see two hp laserjet p1102w printers, do not use the printer that was automatically installed by the system, use the one that the  hp setup tool install for you, by default the working printer name is: `HP_LaserJet_Professional_P_1102w`

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20160316030640/http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/smartinstall/SmartInstallDisable-Tool.run