# hp-setup fails to install USB printer after new kernel installation

Tags: printing, hp

After updating the kernel in Ubuntu 22.04.1 to 5.15.0-60-generic, my HP laser printer quit working, so I attempted to run HP's hp-setup app.  It wouldn't work, so I've removed it and reinstalled the latest version multiple times, but on each run, it will not recognise any USB printers connected to it (although my printer shows up in lsusb).  What is going on?  I'd like to have access to my printer once again!  I've researched this thoroughly and cannot find anything to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

This old question ended up helping me: [HP laserjet p1102w can't disable smart install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/896370/hp-laserjet-p1102w-cant-disable-smart-install) .  Unfortunately, though, the utility the answer alludes to is no longer available on HP's website, so I was not able to disable this Smart Install function that is no longer supported by HP (and which was preventing installation in Ubuntu).  I have a Windows installation, however, so I was able to boot into it and install the utility mentioned on this page: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Printer-Setup-Software-Drivers/How-to-disable-smartinstall-on-windows-10-p1102w/td-p/6262621 .