# How I can update gcc from v 4.4.3 to 4.6.1?

Tags: 10.04, updates, gcc

How I can safely upgrade gcc compiler v 4.4.3 to 4.6.1 under Ubuntu 10.04?

I tried:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /etc/apt/secring.gpg --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 60C317803A41BA51845E371A1E9377A2BA9EF27F
gpg: requesting key BA9EF27F from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key BA9EF27F: public key "Launchpad Toolchain builds" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
igor@igor-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install gcc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gcc is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 28 not upgraded.
```

No success :(

Comment: try searching for gcc-4.6 from synaptic and install. Adding ppa upgrades the versions if they are already installed so you may try `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: After adding a PPA, you should always run a `sudo apt-get update` in order to include the PPAs packages ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The particular PPA you have pointed to in your question will update your GCC compiler from v4.4 to v4.5.

N.B. You need to run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` to uplift to this later version.

On launchpad I have found this [PPA which looks promising](https://launchpad.net/~euroford/+archive/toolchain-bleed-experiment) to uplift lucid to gcc4.6 or this from the [linaro maintainers](https://launchpad.net/~linaro-maintainers/+archive/toolchain/?field.series_filter=lucid).

**Note** - I'm not making any claims about the veracity of these PPAs.  Please see possible related questions below.

---

Related Questions:

- [image: Stack Overflow] [Are "PPA's" safe to add to my system, and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)
- [image: Stack Overflow] [How to install ppa packages in an apt-get style](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16211/how-to-install-ppa-packages-in-an-apt-get-style)