# how to install Qt Creator IDE version 2.4.1 with repository?

Tags: repository, qt-creator

I'm trying to install Qt Creator IDE version 2.4.1 with repository but there is Qt Creator IDE version 2.2.1, I searched but didn't find repository to download qt. just found the offline QT Creator Installer from site of Nokia .

should i download the offline installer ?

Comment: It's in ppa: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtcreator ... possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/16211/how-to-install-ppa-packages-in-an-apt-get-style

Comment: i add the repository but there isn't any upgrades !!!

Comment: it's in ppa for precise.  judging from the history, they're not planning on pushing it back to 11.x

Comment: ok,i got this error while updating repositories `failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/launchpad.net/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found` what should i write exactly in terminal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in ppa for precise.  Either switch to precise when it goes stable April 26th or use the binary installer.

Options:
Wait for April 26th.
Use beta(but then you can't ask questions here...)

Use the binary installer for your architecture from [here](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/).  The procedure is documented [here](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/sdk-linux-x11-64bit-cpp-offline) which is the page you get when you click Offline installer on the previous.

"On Linux/Unix, you need to make the file executable in order to run it. You can either do this with your desktop's file manager or, at the command line, type:"

```
chmod u+x Qt_SDK_Lin64_offline_v1_2_en.run
```

You should now be able to execute the file as normal. You can do this from the command line by typing:

```
./Qt_SDK_Lin64_offline_v1_2_en.run
```